# How to render an entire page from external php page?

Tags: 7

I'm creating a custom .php page that is outside my drupal installation and it should render a custom page of the installation. The "entire" page, also with theme and everything else.

I'm using this code, works but is not loading the theme:

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Root directory of Drupal installation.
     */
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/home/quickstart/websites/custom.dev');

    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);


    drupal_deliver_html_page('user');
    ?>
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you want entire Drupal, with all there is, you need to use all it's code. Simply copy or include `index.php` and you will have all you need, right?

Comment: I try it, but I obtain a page without theme, it doesn't load css etc.

Comment: So it's without theme or without CSS? that's pretty different thing. If it's the CSS, check with Firebug or similar tool - maybe paths are wrong now?

Comment: I tried with your code with a only difference is defining the DRUPAL_ROOT as I am keeping the file in drupal root, its working though I am using bartik as theme and theme css files are loading

Comment: Css is not present in <head>. Your .php file is outside document root?

Comment: If I copy this prova.php file inside the document root it works

Answer (score 1):

[`drupal_deliver_html_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7) is never called directly; you should eventually call [`drupal_deliver_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_page/7). It also seem you are calling the function with the wrong argument, since `drupal_deliver_html_page()` doesn't get a path as argument, but the result obtained by a page callback.

The correct code would be the following one.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/home/quickstart/websites/custom.dev');

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler('user');
```

Since that is just the [index.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/7) code just slightly modified, I don't see any reason not to use http://example.com/user directly. A custom PHP file like that should be used to perform specific tasks, like in the case of [cron.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/cron.php/7).

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

if (!isset($_GET['cron_key']) || variable_get('cron_key', 'drupal') != $_GET['cron_key']) {
  watchdog('cron', 'Cron could not run because an invalid key was used.', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  drupal_access_denied();
}
elseif (variable_get('maintenance_mode', 0)) {
  watchdog('cron', 'Cron could not run because the site is in maintenance mode.', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  drupal_access_denied();
}
else {
  drupal_cron_run();
}
```

Normally, you don't need to use a similar file, and you should handle it through a normal menu callback; this even more true when you need to just shown a specific page as you are doing.

Keep in mind that Drupal 8 doesn't use anymore the cron.php file; cron tasks are handled through a menu callback too.

Comment: I've already used something like cron.php, or hook_menu. The problem is that the same script inside the document root works fine (page with theme), outside the document root the theme is not loaded.

Comment: That is because the links depend from the document root. If the domain name is example.com and /home/quickstart/websites/custom.dev is the directory where Drupal is installed, the absolute URLs always start with http://example.com.

Comment: So is there not a solution for my question?

Comment: For the code you showed, yes: Use http://example.com/user directly.

Comment: My question was another, I know that I can use /user directly :)